# how to create a unix command

Tags: linux, unix

I have a shell script named remote_execution.sh. Is it possible that I just type `remote_execution` in any of the folders and the execution starts, just like gcc, vi or any such command does?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: surely this has to be a dupe?

Comment: This doesn't really deserve to be an answer, but you could make a directory especially for your scripts and add that directory to your $PATH. Google "add directory to $PATH" for info on that.

Answer (score 7):

The following four steps should allow you to run `remote_execution` from anywhere in your filesystem:

1. Rename the file to `remote_execution`, removing the `.sh` extension
2. Add a "[shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)" line to the top of the file

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ```
3. Modify the [permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions) of the file so it is executable (see `man chmod`)

   ```
   chmod u+x remote_execution
   ```
4. Move the file into a directory in your [`PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) so it "works in any folder". At a guess:

   ```
   mv remote_execution /usr/local/bin
   ```

Comment: How do you know that this is a bash script? How do you know it is missing a shebang? That it isn't already executable? That it is not in the PATH? Shouldn't he need to do a `sudo mv remote_execution /usr/local/bin` to write to /usr/local/bin?

Comment: @userunknown It's called probability. Assumptions were made, and they were safe assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is set an  alias

```
alias  remote_execution="fullpath to  remote_execution.sh"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could put that script in any folder depicted by `$PATH`

```
$ echo $PATH

[andreas@nyert test]$ echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/andreas/bin
```

rename your script to `remote_execution` and put `#!/bin/sh` in the first line. Also chmod it to make sure it's executable

```
$ chmod 755 remote_execution
```

Answer (score 1):

add the directory in which remote_execution.sh is located to your `$PATH` variable. Also if you want it to be launched without the ending `.sh`, rename the script to `remote_execution`

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 ways: you either copy the script in one of the directories found in `PATH` or create a symlink for the script there (`ln -s`) or add the current directory of the shell script to the `PATH` (`export PATH=$PATH:dir`).

To find out what `PATH` looks like do a `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have two options, put the script somewhere on your path, or append the script's directory to your path in your `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Each file has it's own permission bits. You have to modify the permissions of the file so it is executable. So use command -

```
chmod +x remote_execution
```

Hoping you have added "[shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)" line to the top of the file

```
#!/bin/bash
```

If you call the script with an explicit interpreter, like

```
bash remote_execution.sh
/bin/bash remote_execution.sh
dash remote_execution.sh
sh remote_execution.sh
```

your choosen interpreter is used, no matter what the shebang says, which is just a comment. Otherwise the kernel looks for the shebang and starts the program with the therein specified interpreter. If Shebang character is used then no matter what extension is !

Your shell is a program. It has variables, one of them is `$ PATH`

`$PATH` contains A colon-separated list of directories to search for commands

If you want to see it just type `$ echo $PATH` in terminal.

On my computer it shows

```
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

This means if I type command like gcc or vim it searches in above directory list.

Now just copy your shell script to any of above folder to access it from anywhere.